# So, what's the meaning of ' By now he'd be an old man'? Does 'by now' emphasize the time in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I am learning English! There's something that I don't understand. May I know the usage of 'by now'?

In the sentence:

> By now he'd be an old man

... does 'by now' emphasize the time?

Comment: It means if he had lived from then (in the past) til now, he'd be old. Meaning he died a long time ago.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67145/how-and-when-should-i-use-by-now

Comment: @Dan Bron It could be a reference to someone whom you hadn't seen for many years and, if he were still alive, would now be an old man. I don't agree that it means he's dead.

Comment: What @Ronald Sole said. If the speaker *knew* the person he was talking about was definitely dead already, he'd more likely say *By now he'd've / **he would have been** an old man* (if he hadn't died).

Comment: Anyways 'would' means "he is guessing.", right?

Comment: Is 'by' non-obligatory here? I'm not sure 'by now' is a prepositional phrase with 'by' meaning 'before'. @FumbleFingers

Comment: Kinzle B: 'by' isn't *grammatically* necessary (per @jacksmith's answer, 'by' simply emphasises the *change over time*). But idiomatically I think it would be rather unusual to omit it in such a statement *starting* with the adverbial clause (but not if you put it at the *end* - there's nothing particularly unusual about *He'd be an old man now*). I think maybe that's just because it's easier and more natural to stress ***now*** at the end of an utterance like that, but perhaps it's just meaningless "established idiomatic preference".

Comment: ...note that ***by** [now, then, next week, etc.]* doesn't exactly mean ***before** [the specified time]* - it means *before or **at** that time*.

Comment: "By now he'd be an old man" does not necessarily mean the person is dead or died long ago, it just means significant time has passed since the point of initial connection with the person.

Answer (score 3):

"By now" emphasizes the change in time between a past point and the present. In your example "by now he'd be an old man" we are emphasizing a long span of time between our connection with the person and their current state.

Comment: Sure thing, have I answered your question?